# Soop import Mssql Incremental

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sqoop

I get a error when I am trying to import from mssql with sqoop. I do a incremental import with lastmodified option on a datetime field.
When sqoop generates bounding vals queries `(SELECT MIN([CODE_ID]), MAX([CODE_ID]) FROM [tablename] WHERE ( [DATETIME_COLUM] >= '2000-01-01' AND [DATETIME_COLUMN] < '2014-05-27 18:13:47.073')`,
 I get an error because the datetime format is not correct.

> Error :
>       Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: convert char to datetime error.

Can I specified to sqoop a datetime format  ?

Here is my command :

> sqoop import –connect ‘jdbc:sqlserver://;databasename=XXX;username=XXX;password=XXX’ –table ‘tablename’ –hbase-table Table –column-family OFE –hbase-row-key CODE_ID –incremental lastmodified –check-column DATETIME_COLUMN –last-value '2000-01-01'

Answer (score 0):

I find myself the solution, so I share it.
The problem was that my mssql database was in french format, so to resolve the problem with the sqoop query import is to add in the query the Datetime format before. So the right command is :

```
    sqoop import -connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://;databasename=;username=sa;password=;'  
    -query 'SET DATEFORMAT ymd;select * from table where $CONDITIONS'  
    -incremental lastmodified -check-column DATE –last-value '2000-01-01'
```

Hope it can help.